# Why doesn't Acid Arrow go against Spell Resistance?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, wizard, spell-resistance

I've seen and understand that Acid Arrow doesn't go against Spell Resistance, as shown [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/acidArrow.htm). But I have no clear idea for a basis of why this would be the case? Even if you were flinging the dart that is your focus, why wouldn't the magical acid be set against SR? You are not, for the record, the text of the spell states you conjure an arrow.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48314/8610).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've already given the reason - [*acid arrow*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/acidArrow.htm) is a [Conjuration (Creation)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#creation) spell.

> A creation spell manipulates matter to create an object or creature in the place the spellcaster designates (subject to the limits noted above). If the spell has a duration other than instantaneous, magic holds the creation together, and when the spell ends, the conjured creature or object vanishes without a trace. If the spell has an instantaneous duration, the created object or creature is merely assembled through magic. It lasts indefinitely and does not depend on magic for its existence.

The acid isn't actually magical. It's created via magic, and its existence is dependent on magic, but it is, itself, actual, real acid. To further hammer this point home, Spell Resistance [has this to say about Conjuration spells](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellResistance):

> These spells are usually not subject to spell resistance unless the spell conjures some form of energy. Spells that summon creatures or produce effects that function like creatures are not subject to spell resistance.

Comment: Okay, but my problem with this interpretation is, either its actual acid and would stick with you much longer than a few rounds, or its acid held together with magic, as per the rules, meaning there's magic to put against the SR. As per the text of the spell, the acid isn't magical, but the arrow delivering it is, so SR could just have it bounce off. I see the rules, but they don't make sense in this case, imho, which is the problem with sweeping statements such as setting the interaction versus the entire school of magic, when there are several different ways its effects work.

Comment: @Arenn The arrow is also a mundane object held together by magic. And SR can't resist that magic, because it's not directed at the creature with SR. If you want to disrupt the magic holding an acid arrow together, use Dispel Magic.