# What is the source of the persistent rumor that D&D 3.5's Orb spells were written to provide an advantage in the writer's home game?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, history-of-gaming, designer-reasons

D&D 3.5's *Complete Arcane* introduced the Orb of Fire/Acid/Whatever line of spells. They are conjuration spells (normally you might expect them to be evocation), they do a reasonably large pile of damage, ignore spell resistance, and even work through antimagic fields.

I have occasionally heard rumors from very different sources that one of the authors of *Complete Arcane* had a favorite character who was a conjurer with evocation banned, and snuck the Orbs in for advantage for that character.

See for example @HeyICanChan's first comment on his answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/148768/25662), though I have also heard it from other forums and from offline friends who have no apparent connection to here or the other forums.

So: Where does this idea come from? Was there an interview where the author said or implied this was the case?

Comment: Of note, _acid orb_, _lesser acid orb_, etc, previously appeared in the 3.0 book _Tome and Blood_ as evocation. _Complete Arcane_ made them Conjuration. According to [Product Spotlight: Complete Arcane](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031220033/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ps/20041105b), suggests that [Mike Donais](https://twitter.com/mike_donais) adapted the spells for the warmage class, but it's not clear why he would change the type to Conjuration.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why is tracking down the rumor's *source* important? It seems like it'd be more interesting—albeit still, I think, ultimately irrelevant—to know if the rumor were true. (By *irrelevant* I mean that knowing if it were true still won't change the rules.) (Also, given that I've helped spread this rumor, and the question mentions me, I should make clear: I am sincerely not this rumor's origin!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Evidence of truth would be a very clear source; I'm just unwilling to ask for anything less concrete (because I fear it would be bait for bad answers). I actually started thinking about this because of some assertion in meta that nothing like this happened in D&D, so it's for it's own sake, not for gameplay. I *strongly suspected* you were not the original source.

Comment: I strongly suspect this and the cat/wizard  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/185188/78357 Are actually: **rumors started based on no facts but sound so plausible they grow to become facts** I also remember hearing this around the time the book came out, but I think I learned about it via email.

Comment: The 3.5 revision changed some spells' schools in the PHB, but these appear to have been generally for reasons of logic, rather than necessarily specialist wizard balance. In fact, _ray of frost_ changed from Conjuration to Evocation in 3.5. However, there was a general move to [balance specialist wizards in 3.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20060207230216/http://www.andycollins.net/Theories/threepointfive_theories.htm), and the conjurer certainly needed a 1st-level offensive spell. Perhaps ask Mike Donais on Twitter, since he is a likely candidate for the guy who made the change.